# Using threads with MinGW?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mingw, mingw-w64

I am building a small tool that will need to open a thread, and let the thread do its thing, no matter what happens on that thread I don't want it to interfere with the main app, just execute, handle errors and close.

How can I do this with mingw compiler? On linux I can use POSIX, but this tool will run only on win, both x86 and x64, so I've no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/). It implements most of pthreads functionality using Windows threading API.

To find this, I searched Google for "pthreads mingw" and it was the first result.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to work directly with Windows threads you'll probably want a cross-platform thread library like [pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/announcement.html) or [boost:thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html)