# Issue with std::thread when using g++ in 32-bit MinGW 4.8.0

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mingw, stdthread

**BACKGROUND** -- We develop `C++11` code and write unit tests using gtest/gmock.  This is built on a Windows server using SCons and `g++` in `MinGW`.  We started having occasional problems when executing unit tests: silent exits, expectation errors, exception pop-ups... with no obvious pattern or commonality and not easily reproduceable.  Eventually, a colleague narrowed it down to a case when apparently a thread was joined without even starting to execute its payload function.  In this case, there were no exceptions or alike.  The test simply failed due to expectation not being met.  I then made a further simpler test case involving neither our codebase nor gtest/gmock.

**BRIEF QUESTION** -- Consider the following code snippet:

```
bool flag(false);
std::thread worker( [&] () { flag = true; } );
worker.join();
assert(flag);
```

When executed **once**, this appears to work **fine**.  By "once" I mean once in the test executable.  This executable is then run repeatedly many times from a command file.

However, when executed **repeatedly** within the test itself, the above assertion would often **fail**; sometimes on the very second repetition, other times after many thousands repetitions.

It appears g++ `std::thread` does not behave well under MinGW (4.8.0/32)  --  Thread is successfully (i.e. no exceptions) created, it is joinable, and it can be joined.  However, in some cases its payload function in never executed.  --  I know MinGW does not have full POSIX pthreads and I already looked at [Using threads with MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727796/using-threads-with-mingw), [pthread_create not enough space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605925/pthread-create-not-enough-space), [MinGW and std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718904/mingw-and-stdthread), and alike to no avail.  We do use static linking (for a different reason) and I also found https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57740.

It all kind of points to a race condition in thread implementation.  Making both boolean flags in the test `volatile` and turning optimization off (`-O0`) made no difference.

We currently use **g++** in **32-bit MinGW version 4.8.0** (out-of-the-box from QT5.1 installation) and are now considering move to a different toolchain (e.g. gcc/g++ on a Linux box) or at least upgrading to later MinGW if there is an indication that this problem might have been fixed.

*Is this a known problem with std::thread on MinGW?*  *Are there any fixes or work-arounds?*  (I mean *general* fixes.  I already implemented some case-by-case- work-arounds that seem to work but I do not like them.)

**FULL DETAILS** -- Executing the code below we note that:

**[A]** Running the code below (so far) execution never fails test at **#2**.  [Expected]

**[B]** However, test at **#4** quite frequently fails (after different number of repetition, including just two(!) repetitions; though sometimes it takes thousands before the test fails).  [Unexpected]

**[C]** Exclusively enabling wait at **#1** results in **more** failures of condition at **#4** (test at **#2** still does not fail).  [Unexpected]

**[D]** Exclusively enabling wait at **#3** makes tests at both **#2** and **#4** succeed.  [Hmm...]

With [D] "fix" and after **many thousands** repetition, I have seen (twice so far) dreaded R6016 (-not enough space for thread data).  (In a way, this is understandable and perhaps not so worrying as long as thread resources are recovered periodically between tests and tests are not run back-to-back.)

Note that the "waits" at #1 and #3 are only to illustrate - they don't have time-out and could possibly hang.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

int main(int, char *[])
{
   bool flag1(false);
   assert(not flag1);

   std::thread worker1( [&] () { flag1 = true; } );
   assert(worker1.joinable());

// while (not flag1) { std::this_thread::yield(); } // #1: MAKES #4 FAIL MORE OFTEN

   worker1.join();
   if (not flag1) // #2: DOES NOT FAIL
   {
      puts("Oops on first!");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   bool flag2(false);
   assert(not flag2);

   std::thread worker2( [&] () { flag2 = true; } );
   assert(worker2.joinable());

// while (not flag2) { std::this_thread::yield(); } // #3: MAKES #4 SUCCEED

   worker2.join();
   if (not flag2) // #4: SOMETIMES FAILS
   {
      puts("Oops on second!");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   puts("Both OKAY");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled into test.exe, the above test can be run repeatedly using:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,1000000) DO (
   ECHO __ %%i ________________________________________________________________________________ %%i __
   test.exe
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO gameover
)
:gameover
```

**EDIT**

- As @TC pointed out, using bool is not correct.  Originally, I used `atomic_bool` with the same behavior as described above.  I then wrongly "simplified" the example to bool.
- BTW using only `yield` without checking the flag at #1 and #3 is **not** sufficient.

Comment: It looks like a memory barrier or optimization barrier is missing around either thread creation or thread joining.

Comment: Seems it's a bug. I have exactly the same result on my MinGW 4.8.0 with code you provided. I also tried this with online compilers (IdeOne and http://melpon.org/wandbox) and there was not any problems

Comment: I have case-by-case workarounds but not general fix (on application side is fine for now).  Ideas?

Comment: Side note: Both #1 and #3 induce a data race and therefore undefined behavior.

Comment: You are correct.  I used atomic_bool at first but then (wrongly) simplified to simple bool.  BTW I had the exact same behavior with the atomic version.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the very detailed analysis and for the great example! 
I've checked this example with x86_64-w**64**-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.8.2, 
flags:
 -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -m64 -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads 
running under 
**Windows 7 with flag -std=c++0x**
It failed rather early each time on second (loop iteration 293, 805, 1632, 276)

**Windows 7 with flag -std=c++11**
It failed rather early each time on second (loop iteration 4, 257, 613, 49)

**Windows 10 with flag -std=c++0x**
It failed after a long time (loop iteration 44924) on second.

**Windows 10 with flag -std=c++11**
It failed after a long time (loop iteration 7389, 41907) on second.

No optimizations where used. 
The tests where done in a VirtualBox with clean installations of Windows 7/10 without updates. 
The test executables required the libraries:

- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll

So it is definitely much more stable under Windows 10, but not flawless. 
Using c++11 instead of c++0x might be less stable under Windows7. But I've run too few tests to be certain about that.
Has anybody tried with a newer version of MinGW?